# Possible to disable jNice (jQuery plugin) for IE6?

Tags: jquery

We're using the jNice plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jNice) to style form inputs. It doesn't play well with IE6 and we want to disble it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't add the `jNice` class to your `form` element.
2. Use the following to run jNice:

   ```
   jQuery(function ($) {
       if (!($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7)) {
           $('form').jNice();
       }
   });
   ```

You can also use the IE conditional markup suggested by others:

```
<![if gte IE 7]>
    <script src="jquery.jNice.js"></script>
<![endif]>
```

IE conditionals are a better solution because they won't fail in the event of browser spoofing (where the browser pretends it has a different user agent).  However, they don't produce valid XHTML (afaik) and aren't as flexible.

Comment: A much nicer approach than my own (now deleted) attempt.

Comment: Agreed, I had forgotten about jquery's browser detection, this is a very good way to do it.

Comment: IE conditionals are a better solution because they won't fail in the event of browser spoofing (where the browser pretends it has a different user agent).